# Please I am Unable to launch android studio 3.12 Emulator on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: android, android-emulator

Please I need help here , I was trying to run Emulator on android studio on my system but this are the error it is showing on the event log.

> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: driver pointer missing
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer
>   parameter out of range for operation)
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: Minor opcode of failed request:  24
>   (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: Value in failed request:  0x0
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: Serial number of failed request:  64
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: Current serial number in output stream:  65
>
> 1:30 AM   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1